# Can't load model from Json or Yaml file or with load_model function

Tags: python, json, keras, yaml, lstm

I am trying to load a model with the following ways but nothing seems to work.

Json:

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open('C:/Users/path/model.json', "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("C:/Users/path/ΔΙΠΛΩΜΑΤΙΚΗ/model_json_1.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

Load from Json file:

```
json_file = open('C:/Users/path/model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json, {"tf":tf})
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("C:/Users/path/model_json_1.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

Yaml:

```
model_yaml = model.to_yaml()
with open("C:/Users/path/model.yaml", "w") as yaml_file:
    yaml_file.write(model_yaml)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("C:/Users/path/model_yam.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

Load model from Yaml file:

```
yaml_file = open('C:/Users/path/model.yaml', 'r')
loaded_model_yaml = yaml_file.read()
yaml_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_yaml(loaded_model_yaml)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("C:/Users/path/model_yam.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

I also trying the following:

```
model.save("C:/Users/user/Desktop/ΔΙΠΛΩΜΑΤΙΚΗ/model_save.h5")
```

Load model:

```
model = load_model('C:/Users/path/model_save.h5', compile = False)
```

I get the same error from all the above ways.
ERROR:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

I build my model with the following way.

MODEL:

```
 print('Build model...')
    main_input = Input(shape=(maxlen, num_features), name='main_input')
    
    l1 = LSTM(100, implementation=2, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', return_sequences=True, dropout=0.2)(main_input) # the shared layer
    
    b1 = BatchNormalization()(l1)
  
    l2_1 = LSTM(100, implementation=2, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', return_sequences=False, dropout=0.2)(b1) # the layer specialized in activity prediction
   
    b2_1 = BatchNormalization()(l2_1)
    
    l2_2 = LSTM(100, implementation=2, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', return_sequences=False, dropout=0.2)(b1) # the layer specialized in time prediction
   
    b2_2 = BatchNormalization()(l2_2)
    
    act_output = Dense(len(target_chars), activation='softmax', kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='act_output')(b2_1)
    
    time_output = Dense(1, kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform', name='time_output')(b2_2)
    
    model = Model(inputs=[main_input], outputs=[act_output, time_output])
    
    opt = Nadam(lr=0.002, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, schedule_decay=0.004, clipvalue=3)
  
    lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.5, patience=10, verbose=0, mode='auto', min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0)
   
model.fit(X, {'act_output':y_a, 'time_output':y_t}, validation_split=0.2, verbose=2, callbacks=[early_stopping, model_checkpoint, lr_reducer], batch_size=maxlen, epochs=500)
```

Does that error maybe means that I am building my model wrong.?
What can I do to fix that error.?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe the version of the TensorFlow that you used to save the model is different from the one that you are using to load the model

Comment: Try this: `load_model(model_path, compile=False)`